# mysql insert if doesn't exist update

Tags: mysql

I have more then 1 million records in tables.

```
   user_id name_id
    1       1
    1       2 
    2       1
```

I have this structure and I need:

```
insert into (user_id,name_id) (1,2)
```

1. if record exist = update name_id
2. if record doen't exist insert
   user_id and name_id

Who can write example for it? It should work fast.

Comment: Did you have a look at the MySQL manual?

Comment: I want ask your advice, who did this already.

Comment: @RadchenkoViktor: you're supposed to come prepared. Show us that you tried and failed.

Answer (score 4):

```
insert into users (user_id, name_id)
values (1, 2)
on duplicate key update
  name_id = values(name_id);
```

You're gonna need a unique index for `on duplicate key` to work.